# Why is timepicker null in this page?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-timepicker

I have written this page of HTML and am having problems locating my datepicker controls using jQuery when I handle an event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>DatePicker error</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">

        <form id="createBooking" method="post" action="/Booking/Create">
            <div class="row" id="page1">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="StartDateDate">From</label>
                        <input id="StartDateDate"
                               name="StartDateDate"
                               type="text"
                               data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy"
                               value="18/10/2018"
                               Title="Create" class="form-control" data-date="10/18/2018" />

                        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="StartDateDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="EndDateDate">From</label>
                        <input id="EndDateDate"
                               name="EndDateDate"
                               type="text"
                               data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy"
                               value="18/10/2018"
                               Title="Create" class="form-control" data-date="10/18/2018" />

                        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="StartDateDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>


    </div>
    <script>
        console.log('Binding changeDate handlers');
        $('#EndDateDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
            //Script fails here with datepicker not defined...
            var startDate = $('#StartDateDate').datepicker('getDate');
            return true;
        });
        $('#StartDateDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (e) {
            //Script fails here with datepicker not defined...
            var endDate = $('#EndDateDate').datepicker('getDate');
            return true;
        });
<!--    </script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

However, When I run it it fails saying datepicker is not defined in the changeDate event handlers. I am referencing the latest version of all the various libraries.

Has anyone any idea what I am doing wrong? It is defined correctly when the events are attached but the selector method doesn't seem to have it.

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

If you uncomment the cloudfare links at the top it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
```

Which would suggest your paths are wrong or the files do not exist in that location. Does the file `/lib/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.min.js` actually exist?

Press F12 in the browser and check the Console.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me - this is strange. I uncomment the cloudfare lines and get the following: `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'dates' of undefined or null reference` in `
bootstrap-datepicker.en-GB.min.js (1,13)`. When you say 'works' do you get an error in the console when you change dates? I do but the datepicker object exists outside the event handler but not in it

Answer (score 0):

I think this was down to multiple inclusions oj jQuery. I wish it warned you it was included more than once!